# How to redirect this sharing image to an external link?

Tags: magento, redirect, hyperlink, sharing

I want to redirect these sharing images to their respective sites..

I have a code as this..!

```
 <identifier>block_footer_top2_left</identifier>
     <content><![CDATA[<div class="social-links">

<a class="first" href="#" title="Follow us on Twitter">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-twitter-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Join us on Facebook">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-facebook-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Join us on Google Plus">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-googleplus-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Youtube">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-youtube-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Vimeo">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-vimeo-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Wordpress">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-wordpress-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Pinterest">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-pinterest-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Linked in">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-linkedin-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Blogger">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-blogger-w"></span>
</a>
<a href="#" title="Envato marketplaces">
    <span class="icon icon-hover i-envato-w"></span>
</a>
```

But when I write www.facebook.com/mypage instead of # in the code...

The page opens as www.mysite.com/index/www.facebook.com/mypage

and that gives my 404 Error

How to redirect it to my facebook page..?

Answer (score 0):

add `http://www.facebook.com/mypage` in stead of `www.facebook.com/mypage`. Will work.

If want to open in new window then add: `target="_blank"` in anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

try to write url like this

```
http://www.facebook.com/

append http:: in url
```

just example

```
<a title="Facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/mypage" target="_blank">
```